# Custom SVG shape clip path image

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

Been trying to work this out but have wasted so much time I think its best for me to just ask.

The objective is to have custom (responsive) shapes - which house an image (example below):

[image]

I've followed some online sources and have managed to get this (kinda) working with:

SVG custom path and clip-path

```
<header>
<h1><span class="text-shadow">Hiking</span><br>
    <span class="text-shadow">The Pinicles</span><br>
    <span class="text-shadow">NZ</span></h1>

<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id='clipper'>
      <path d="M0 830.5V0.500008H514C514 0.500008 575.5 0.500008 632.5 146.5C689.5 292.5 239.5 646.667 0 830.5Z" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<img class="headerIMG" src="/ASSETS/IMG/blog-images/mountain.JPG" alt="">
```

And applying the clip path to the image:

```
    img.headerIMG {
    clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
```

Result:

[image]

What I am trying to do and failing at is:

1. moving the IMG to position it so that a different part of the photo is showing (not the top left)
2. resizing the SVG clip path so it could be 100vh or 50vh depending on the media query used.

---

Any help here would be great and please feel free to ask any questions you might have to better understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492086/8620333

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65457332/svg-clip-path-resizing-according-to-viewport/65458270#65458270

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to move the image independently from the clip path.  But they boil down to applying the clip to a parent element, so you can move the image around within it.

For example

```
<div class="headerIMG-container">
  <img class="headerIMG" src="/ASSETS/IMG/blog-images/mountain.JPG" alt="">
</div>

.headerIMG-container {
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}

.headerIMG {
  transform: tarnslate(0, -100px);
}
```

or something like

```
<div class="headerIMG></div>

.headerIMG {
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
  background: url(/ASSETS/IMG/blog-images/mountain.JPG) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 100px;
}
```

or do it all in the SVG

```
<svg width="400" height="300">
  <defs>...clip...</defs>

  <g clip-path="url(#clipper)">
    <image class="headerIMG" xlink:href="/ASSETS/IMG/blog-images/mountain.JPG" width="???" height="???" transform="translate(0, -100)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```